# Send out email/campaign to a list when url is visited in mailchimp

Tags: php, api, curl, automation, mailchimp

Hello Stackoverflow :)

I'm building a script for a client that has an e-paper that comes out everyday.

The e-paper is build by a 3rd party and when they publish it, they can have their system visit an URL of our choice.

When their system visits our URL we wan't a mailchimp automated e-mail (with a link to the e-paper) to be send out to everyone on one of our lists.

**So my question is:** Can the automated paid feature in Mailchimp do this for us or do we need to code a script with the mailchimp API at the URL to take care of the automated e-mail to the lists? And if the latter which methods should I look into in the documentation?

Not looking for a complete answer, but a pointing in the right direction :)

Google hasn't helped me with the following queries: "send out email to a list when url is visited", "send email campaign to list when url is visited" which is why I now turn to you :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in all it's glory! And it' fixes the issue I had :)

```
<?php
        /**
         * Method for communicating with mailchimp API
         *
         * @param str   $method  Which url you need to access in the Mailchimp API
         * @param str   $type Which type of request (POST, GET etc)
         * @param array $data Do you need to pass data along aswell in a multi dimensional array?
         * 
         * @author Kenneth Johnsen <Johns3n@gmail.com>
         * @return Server Header Response
         */ 
        function request($method,$type, $data = false){
            $apiKey = '<API KEY>';
            $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);

            $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0'.$method;

            $ch = curl_init($url);

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $type);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

            if($data){
                curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
            }

            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            curl_close($ch);

            return $result;
        }


        // GET VARIABLES THAT MIGHT CHANGE DEPENDING ON E-PAPER SUPPLIER:
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $paper = 'Name of Company';
        $replyTo = 'noreply@companyname.com';
        $templateId = 65;


        // CREATE CAMPAIGN AND RETURN THE ID SO WE CAN EDIT IT ASWELL:
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $campaign = array(
            'type' => 'regular',
            'recipients' => array(
                    'list_id' => '<LIST ID>'
                ),
            'settings' => array(
                    'subject_line' => 'E-paper for '.$paper.' is now ready!',
                    'title' => $paper.' E-Paper Notification ('.date("d/m-Y").')',
                    'from_name' => $paper,
                    'reply_to' => $replyTo,

                )
        );

        $createCampaign = request('/campaigns','POST',$campaign);
        $createCampaign = json_decode($createCampaign);


        // EDIT THE CAMPAIGN TO MATCH TEMPLATE ID:
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $editCampaign = array(
            'template' => array(
                    'id' => $templateId
                )
        );

        $updateCampaign = request('/campaigns/'.$createCampaign->id.'/content','PUT',$editCampaign);


        // SCHEDULE THE CAMPAIGN FOR LAUNCH FROM NEAREST QUARTER MINUTE + ANOTHER 30 MINUTES:
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $time = time();
        $time = round($time / (15 * 60)) * (15 * 60) + (30 * 60);
        $time = date('i',$time);

        $timeSchedule = date('Y-m-dTH:'.$time.':00+01:00');

        $schedule = array(
            'schedule_time' => $timeSchedule
        );

        $scheduleCampaign = request('/campaigns/'.$createCampaign->id.'/actions/schedule','POST',$schedule);

        var_dump($scheduleCampaign);
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you could use MailChimp's Goal and Automation features to accomplish *something like this*. However, you're dealing with a dynamically generated URL that needs to be included in your email. So far, I haven't come accross a way to transfer information from a "Goal page" to MailChimp - other than the data that is transferred automatically by the Goal script.

So I think you're looking at an API job. You'll need to use "Campaigns" methods (http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/campaigns/).

Please note that creating and sending a campaign are two different steps of the overall process. You'll find the "send" method under "Action" on the same page. Just take the ID returned by the "create" method, feed it into the "send" method and watch the magic happen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The URL is not dynamic and still stay the same and parameters will not be included aswell.. I just need that whenever the URL is visited a e-mail that will not change is send out from mailchimp.

Comment: So...the link to the whitepaper is exactly the same, every day? If that's the case, then Goal + Automation could be the solution.

Comment: Problem I ran into with automation is that I doesn't allow you to send the same e-mail to same person again. However I found a solution using the API that I will post here when im done with the script.. But basically it's creating a new campaign everytime the url is visited and queue it up for launch :)

Comment: Right, that makes sense. So...the good ol' API after all. ;-)